# Several icons are not displaying right

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, icons

Several icons in Windows 7 are not displaying right.

Not all of them. Just some. I don't know what it depends on.

This is what a Word document icon looks like:

[image]

This is what a BitTorrent icon looks like.

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

---

[This answer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2422299/icons-are-not-displayed-for-certain-files-in-windows-7) didn't work for me.

Another screenshot showing Microsoft Office icons not displaying correctly:
[image]

Comment: Please follow the [official tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2422299/icons-are-not-displayed-for-certain-files-in-windows-7)

Comment: I attempted to fix the grammar of this question.  However, the first part of the question, I couldn't improve (not clear).  You should clarify your question though.

Comment: didn't work for me @Jerry

Comment: If you press WIN+R, type `cleanmgr`, hit ENTER and run the utility, deleting everything there, does that do anything?

Comment: @InterLinked i does something but problem is alive. The main problem is with the .docx file (icon)

Comment: @InterLinked the problem is with the .docx files. The .exe icon is ok

Comment: Okay, go to Control Panel, go to Uninstall programs, right-click Office and select "Repair"

Comment: @InterLinked got message ;Configuration of... 2007 was not finished, An unexpected error occured; something like this, i translated it from polish

Comment: Try it again. This is the best way to fix any corrupted file problems that you are having. It may not work the first time. Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80204/discussion-between-krystian2160-and-interlinked).

Comment: @InterLinked had problem with that, tried uninstall with iobit uninstaller, still problem. Found microsoft office total final uninstaller and it worked. then installed again and problem is fixed. So total uninstall + install = works. Thx for time and help dude. have a good day.